# How emulate PDO::getColumnData() using Oracle?

Tags: oracle, pdo, introspection, database-metadata

I have a vanilla PHP  7 app that (aims to) suports MySQL, Postgres, SQL Server and Oracle.

I've faced a problem now because all but Oracle (pdo_oci), supports getColumnData()

```
$statement   = $pdo->query('SELECT titulo, preco FROM livro');
$metadados   = $statement->getColumnMeta(0);
```

MySQL:

```
array(7) { ["native_type"]=> string(10) "VAR_STRING" ["pdo_type"]=> int(2) ["flags"]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(8) "not_null" } ["table"]=> string(5) "livro" ["name"]=> string(6) "titulo" ["len"]=> int(765) ["precision"]=> int(0) }
```

Postgres:

```
array(8) { ["pgsql:oid"]=> int(1043) ["pgsql:table_oid"]=> int(16585) ["table"]=> string(5) "livro" ["native_type"]=> string(7) "varchar" ["name"]=> string(6) "titulo" ["len"]=> int(-1) ["precision"]=> int(259) ["pdo_type"]=> int(2) }
```

SQLServer:

```
array(8) { ["flags"]=> int(0) ["sqlsrv:decl_type"]=> string(7) "varchar" ["native_type"]=> string(6) "string" ["table"]=> string(0) "" ["pdo_type"]=> int(2) ["name"]=> string(6) "titulo" ["len"]=> int(255) ["precision"]=> int(0) }
```

Is there an way to emulate a similar result from the others drivers but using pdo_oci?

Comment: PHP 7.4 adds support to PDO_OCI for this: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76908

Comment: please make a answer with that and I will give you the point !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHP 7.4 adds support to PDO_OCI for this: bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=76908